# Подойдёт ли моё решение для поиска изначальной позиции возрастающей последовательности

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос: подходит ли мой метод поиска индекса последовательности
P.S Принимаю любую аргументированную критику кода

код выполняет следующую задачу : Написать программу, которая читая последовательность чисел из файла, выводит на экран самую длинную возрастающую последовательность, ее длину и позицию (в числах и символах) с которой она началась.

```
import time,os,string,psutil,re
start_time = time.time()
res_list = []
res=''
symbol_len = 1  # Размер буфера чтения
with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    s = file.read(symbol_len)  # Считываем первый символ
    if not s:  # Обработка исключения пустого файла
        print("\nФайл text.txt пустой.")
    else:
        for line in file.readlines():
            x = re.findall(r'\d+', line)

            if x:
                res_list.extend(x)

    res_list.append(res)

    _max = max(res_list, key=len)
    index = res_list.index(_max)
    print (index)
    print(f'Самая длинная восх. посл. - {_max}\nсимволов - {len(_max)}\nначальный индекс - {(index)}')
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in bytes
    print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: выполняет ли задачу верно,по вашему мнению?

Comment: Вы этот код тут уже раз пять поместили:-) Не понимаю проблемы - напишите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. И сами увидите, верно или нет.

Comment: Я в восторге. Помещаете код, известно что он должен делать. Запустить его вам -  ничего не стоит, а вот нам - сложно, потому что нет файла, который он должен читать (другими словами вы не привели воспроизводимый пример). И после этого вы нас спрашиваете -  решает ли этот код вашу задачу? А сами-то вы как думаете?  Мне лень разбираться в вашем коде, поэтому дам наиболее вероятный в такой ситуации ответ  вопрос  -"нет, этот код не выполняет поставленную перед ним задачу и ваше решение "не подойдет"".

Answer (score 0):

Ваша программа не решает поставленную задачу потому что для решения необходимо сравнивать числа для проверки их упорядоченности. Ваша программа работает со строками цифр, не числами. Нигде нет кода которые сравнивает разные числа или строки. Есть код для поиска самого длинного числа или строки. Можно показать на примерах что этого недостаточно.

**P.S.** Мой ответ - ответ на ваш вопрос. Для вас он бесполезен.

Прочитайте [эту статью](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log) про поиск длиннейшей возрастающей подпоследовательности. К сожалению, пока вы не понимаете постановку задачи.